# At which moment current_period_end and current_period_start variables in stripe subscription updates?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have stripes subscription mirror in my db and i want to detect when current_period_end and current_period_start variables changes (on some webhook or etc) to change it in my db.

I do handle invoice.invoice_succeeded in my code but i need actually time when this vars change.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to your question?